# Django dj-rest-auth does not set cookie despite JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE

Tags: django, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, dj-rest-auth

I have a simple Django app managing user autentication and registration with dj-rest-auth and JWT.
Accorging to the [docs](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#json-web-token-jwt-support-optional), I have set the the app to use JWT with the plugin [simple-jwt](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) with settings.py:

- JWT_AUTH_COOKIE = 'my-app-auth'
- JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE = 'my-refresh-token'

**Expected behaviour**: Cookies should be set on /dj-rest-auth/login/ and /token/refresh

**Issue**: Cookies are set correctly ONLY on /dj-rest-auth/login/, but not on /token/refresh.

This issue is not something new, since it is supposed to be solved [here](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/issues/190) and [here](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/issues/97).

So, I also added the suggested [middleware](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/johnckealy/6ee77bde3e06b4d875c982c2d91f152c/raw/4ff67b43b717cecb28925205fb5eea5e65fe2ed6/middleware.py).

Here my settings.py:

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication',
]
}

```
REST_USE_JWT = True
JWT_AUTH_COOKIE = 'my-app-auth'
JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE = 'my-refresh-token'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'auth_app.middleware.MoveJWTRefreshCookieIntoTheBody'
]
```

and my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url, re_path

from auth_app import views

# JWT CONF
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenRefreshView,
    TokenVerifyView,
)

from dj_rest_auth.registration.views import VerifyEmailView, RegisterView
from dj_rest_auth.views import PasswordResetConfirmView
from allauth.account.views import confirm_email

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView().as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('api/protected/', views.ProtectedView.as_view(), name='protected_view'),
    path('api/open/', views.OpenView.as_view(), name='open_view'),
    # dj-rest-auth common
    path('dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    # dj-rest-auth registration
    path('dj-rest-auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('dj-rest-auth/account-confirm-email/', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_email_verification_sent'),
    re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', VerifyEmailView.as_view(),
     name='account_confirm_email'),
    path(
        'rest-auth/password/reset/confirm/<slug:uidb64>/<slug:token>/',
        PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'
    ),
]
```

I have been checking my with the solutions provided for long long time, but still no cookie set on refresh endpoint.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I **SOLVED** this issue!

If anybody in future will struggle with this, here to solution: in *urls.py* you have to substitute the simplejwt **TokenRefreshView** with **get_refresh_view()** which belong to dj-rest-auth.

In other words, the right JWT configuration is:

```
# JWT CONF
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenVerifyView
from dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth import get_refresh_view
```